# ggplot2 plotting coordinates on map using geom_point, unwanted lines appearing between points

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am trying to plot a set of lat/long coordinates on a map of the USA using ggplot2, here is my code:

```
states <- map_data("state")
usamap <- ggplot(states, aes(long, lat, group=1)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "white", colour = "black") + 
  geom_point(data = data_masks2, aes(x = lng, y = lat), alpha = 1, size = 1) +
  theme_cowplot()
```

However, when I plot `usamap` I am getting strange lines connecting some of the points (seen below), and I am unsure why. Why are these appearing, and how do I get rid of them?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's because of `geom_polygon`, if you remove that line, you will not get these lines and by the looks of your code, it looks like you don't `geom_polygon`

Comment: `geom_polygon()` is most definitely needed.  Without that, you don't have a map!  It's drawing your states and in fact is the issue here, but it's more to do with the information you sent to `geom_polygon()` to draw your states.  See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [very helpful vignette available here for creating maps](https://remiller1450.github.io/s230s19/Intro_maps.html), but the issue is with your `geom_polygon()` line.  You definitely need this (as it's the thing responsible for drawing your state lines), but you have the `group=` aesthetic wrong.  You need to set `group=group` to correctly draw the lines:

```
ggplot(states, aes(long, lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "white", colour = "black")
```

[image]

If you use `group=1` as you have, you get the lines:

```
ggplot(states, aes(long, lat, group=1)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "white", colour = "black")
```

[image]

Why does this happen?  Well, it's how `geom_polygon()` (and `ggplot` in general) works.  The `group=` aesthetic tells `ggplot` what "goes together" for a geom.  In the case of `geom_polygon()`, it tells `ggplot` what collection of points need to be connected in order to draw a single polygon- which in this case is a single state.  When you set `group=1`, you are **assigning every point in the dataset to belong to the same polygon**.  Believe it or not, the map with the weird lines is actually composed of a single polygon, with points that are drawn in sequence as they are presented.

Have a look at your `states` dataset and you will see that there is `states$group`, which is specifically designed to allow you to group the points that belong to each state together.  Hence, we arrive at the somewhat confusing statement: `group=group`.  This means "Set the `group=` aesthetic to the value of the `group` column in `states`, or `states$group`."

Comment: great! thanks so much, this makes a lot of sense, and the fix works :)

Comment: I'm glad to help.  If you feel this answers your question, please consider accepting the answer.